# How to handle multiple categories in prediction tasks

Tags: python, regression

So I have a dataset whose column "category" has over 20 different values:

```
category         number of observations 
Academic          16
Apps             920
Blues             17
Comedy             1
Experimental     270
Festivals        382
Flight           272
Gadgets         1650
Hardware        2485
Immersive        222
Makerspaces      155
Musical          649
Places            88
Plays            981
Robots           365
Shorts            33
Software        2008
Sound            384
Spaces           142
Thrillers         18
Wearables        687
Web             2452
Webseries         17
```

I want to use those categories as part of the predictors. In this situation, transforming them into dummy variables don't seem too promising. I am wondering if there is a way to quantify the categories and incorporate them into the prediction model? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: can u give more feedback about ur task

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be about Python.

Comment: Probably you can try to have each category as a column and values of each category in a binary form of being present or not. So, total predictors would be 20+x variables

Comment: I also think this question is much better to be here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ and the tags must be different i suppose